# ThreadPoolExecutor not assigning tasks to worker threads

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent, threadpoolexecutor

My ThreadPoolExecutor is not assigning tasks to worker threads. As I don't know how this problem is arising so will explain current situation.

```
CorePoolSize = 15, 
Max PoolSize = 100, 
KeepAliveTime 5 minutes, 
ArrayBlockingQueue of size 1.
```

Currently

```
executor.getActiveCount() = 0, 
executor.getPoolSize() = 100, 
executor.getQueue().remainingCapacity() = 0
```

I could see my submitted task is in ArrayBlockingQueue but then why these 100 threads simply sitting in threadpool and nobody picking submitted task.

All threads having similar stack trace in jconsole

```
Name: pool-15-thread-182
State: WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync@16926fe3
Total blocked: 396  Total waited: 66

Stack trace: 
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:156)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:811)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:842)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2033)
java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.poll(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:347)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:955)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:917)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:682)
```

Code

Initialization:

```
executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(CORE_THREADPOOL_SIZE, (int)MAX_THREADPOOL_SIZE, KEEP_ALIVE_TIME, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(1), new ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy());
```

Submitting Task:

```
Future<?> futureTask = executor.submit(opmTask);
```

Task:

```
 class OpmTask implements Runnable { 
@Override public void run() {
 .... }
 }
```

Thread Management to kill blocking thread

```
if(future != null && !future.isDone()){
                        future.cancel(true);
                    }
// after 30 minutes of above code if still blocking thread running
if(thread.isAlive()){
                        thread.stop();
                    }
```

Inside run in some internal method

```
while (true) {
                while (InputStream.available() > 0) {
                    int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                    if (i < 0)
                        break;
                    outputStr += new String(tmp, 0, i);
                }

                if(Thread.interrupted()){
                    logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"Thread interrupted");
                    throw new BlockedThreadException("Thread interrupted");
                }
}
```

Comment: could you attach your code? it's hard to debug without seeing it

Comment: MaxPoolSize does not reach 100 unless 100 or more tasks  have been submitted

Comment: Are you sure there is a task for them to run? What is the queue depth/length at this point?

Comment: @efekctive  As you could see executor.getActiveCount() = 0 so there is no working threads now and actually these all 100 threads have finished submitted tasks one or more times. But after that these threads are not being reused. If I increase thread pool size to executor.setMaximumPoolSize(105) then 5 newly created threads actually will pick task and complete and will return to thread pool and having similar stack trace as pasted in question. These 5 threads picks submitted tasks one or more times but after some time these threads are not being reused.

Comment: Please show the code where you setup the ThreadPoolExecutor. Behavior highly depends on that. Have you tried using a queue of size = 2 instead of 1? AFAIK if the queue is bounded and full and threadcount < MaxPoolSize, a new one will be started without checking if there are threads that are idle.

Comment: ActiveCount means there are not tasks to run. So waiting is the natural thing to do for at least five minutes

Comment: Could you shows us the code where you are submitting tasks?

Comment: post it. so we can read. Thank you!!

Comment: Should work fine - it sounds like your tasks might not be completing - put a debug `println()` or something in as their last task to check they are actually finishing. Are your `Future`s reporting `isDone() == true`?

Comment: @Barry I could see run method is completing. Even logs also printing after run method finishes and I think pasted stack trace confirms that thread even returned to thread pool and waiting for new task to come in BlockingQueue.

Comment: And print to console/breakpoint in the last line inside run(). To make sure they are doing what you expect them to do

Comment: @PeterLawrey Queue lenght is 1 at this point.

Comment: if you can see the run() method complete successfully and you are not submitting new tasks what do you expect the thread pool to do for 5 minutes?

Comment: @efekctive If printing of last line of run method confirms Future.isDone = true then I confirm that task is completing for sure.

Comment: @efekctive I am keep submitting tasks every 30 seconds. Problem is that a thread from thread pool is being used only few times. After few task completion thread is stuck with provided stack trace.

Comment: what you have is a bug in your code. Not the thread pool

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137944/discussion-between-sohan-badaya-and-efekctive).

Comment: Sorry I got busy now.

Comment: It take time for a task to be picked up so you might see a queue of N momentarily. A sleeping thread might take 10-100 micro-seconds to wake up and grab a task.

Comment: Do you get RejectedExecutionException from time to time?

Comment: @Fildor Yes I do get RejectedExecutionException sometimes, but I ignore it because every 30 seconds I am getting task list and submitting those tasks to theadpool.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I have ArrayBlockingQueue of size 1 only and threads are not picking tasks after hours also.

Comment: @All Some comments are that possibly my task(run method) is not completing, so if I put future.cancel(true); at the end of run method then threads's task should be assumed completed and the same thread should be good to reuse.

Comment: Can you please first try to increase the capacity of your queue?

Comment: I think you need to create a short reproducible test. Most likely you are doing something wrong but it's not possible to determine what it is from the information given.

Comment: @All Have updated blocked thread stack trace, earlier stack trace was incorrect.

Comment: @All Have updated blocked thread stack trace, earlier stack trace was incorrect.
Also want to add that if my worker thread takes longer than decided time then I am calling future.cancel(true) so it internally calls interrupt on that thread. And worker thread keep checking if Thread.interrupted() then its coming out of run method.

Comment: @All One more query, I am calling thread.stop() on worker thread if thread don't check Thread.interrupted and still running on long running blocking I/O call. I could see stopped threads are not in exist in thread pool. Is calling thread.stop may trigger instability in Thread pool and so remaining worker threads also not working on submitted tasks?

Comment: Don't call thread.stop. close the stream in addition to cancel.

Comment: `Thread.stop()` is generally not the best of ideas. If the blocking I/O call is not interruptible, then `cancel` won't be able to break it. But if you close the underlying stream (I guess it is some kind of stream) from outside it should throw some kind of Exception at the call and wake up the thread, probably an IOException. Then you can gracefully end the thread. Maybe you won't even need to cancel it then.

Comment: For why Thread.stop is bad see the docu: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop-- First of all - it is deprecated and so you may have to replace it anyway in the future.

Comment: @Fildor You are right, calling stop on worker thread is culprit. When I run problem in debug mode in eclipse I could see executor.workQueue.lock.sync.head.thread, its same thread on which I called stop(). As this thread holding lock on ArrayBlockingQueue but its not runnable so its simply blocked.

Comment: I voted to reopen the question. Can you add a little more info about the blocking I/O call? Maybe add the run-code in the question. I think this is key to your problem.

Comment: Is that a network stream? Then available does not what you think it does.  Check the read count for -1 instead.

Comment: The thing is: As is, the `break` if read count is <0 only breaks the *inner* while and your thread still loops in the outer `while(true)` ... But the while over `available` is completely unnecessary. Just remove that while (not its contents).

Answer (score 1):

From your example, this is a bit hard to understand. I would recommend, firstly, to make your threads daemons so they won't block your application shutdown. As for your example, I can not see any misbehaviour. Try this example:

```
public class ExecutorTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(10, (int)10, 5 * 60 , TimeUnit.SECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(1), new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setDaemon(true).build());
        executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy());

        while(true) {
            executor.submit(() -> {
                System.out.println("Executing " + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            });
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }

    }

}
```

Note that this will run forever and print the next line after line after line. Also not that I am passing in a ThreadFactory that configures the executor's threads to be daemons.

As for your stacktrace:

```
Stack trace: 
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:156)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1987)
java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.take(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:322)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:957)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:917)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:682)
```

This does not mean that your Threads are stuck. (well, technically it does, but not in the actual sense). They are waiting for a new task to work on. If you look at your queue implementation: `ArrayBlockingQueue#take`

```
 public E take() throws InterruptedException {
        final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
        lock.lockInterruptibly();
        try {
            while (count == 0)
                notEmpty.await();
            return dequeue();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
```

This is where they are waiting for a new task. They check the queue if it has something else to do and then wait until it does. This will naturally happen for all your threads.

I also find the configuration a tad odd. You configure 100 workers with a queue of maximum size 1. This seems like a recipe to drop tasks.

Also, you are not showing your task implementation, meaning that I am only guessing on how your threadpool behaves on exceptions.

It appears your setup works correctly, but the problem is rather the task or submission itself.